# How to use plugin option in React webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I use importAttributes in babel configuration, but is show this error :

```
: SyntaxError: E:\Flowise\packages\ui\src\App.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'importAttributes' isn't currently enabled (22:5):
flowise-ui:build:   20 |       type: 'css'
flowise-ui:build:   21 |     }
flowise-ui:build: > 22 |   });
flowise-ui:build:      |     ^
flowise-ui:build:   23 |   console.log('cssModule: ', cssModule);
flowise-ui:build:   24 |   return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(StyledEngineProvider, {
flowise-ui:build:   25 |     injectFirst: true
flowise-ui:build: 
flowise-ui:build: Add @babel/plugin-syntax-import-attributes (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-import-attributes) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable parsing.
```

in **package.json**

```
 "babel": {
        "presets": [
            ["@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "node": "current"
                }
            }],
            "@babel/preset-react"
        ],
        "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-import-attributes"]
    },
```

in **craco.config.js
**

```
module.exports = {
    webpack: {
        configure: {
            module: {
                rules: [
                    {
                        test: /\.m?js$/,
                        resolve: {
                            fullySpecified: false
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.(?:js|mjs|cjs)$/,
                        exclude: /node_modules/,
                        use: {
                            loader: 'babel-loader',
                            options: {
                                presets: [
                                    ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: "defaults" }]
                                ],
                                plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-import-attributes']
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve it, I don't know why get this error. I already set the plugin, but it seems to be not found when run it.